# Bind ConstraintLayout guide offset to height of a button

Tags: user-interface, layout, android-constraintlayout

How can I bind **layout_constraintGuide_end** to height of a button?[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="HEIGHT OF BUTTON"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I dont think we really need to limit the guideline height in this case and height should not depend on button since your button depends on this guideline.

Comment: My button doesn't depend on guide line

Comment: app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"

Comment: Sorry copy-paste mistake, removed that attribute.

Comment: You may not need a guideline for what you want to do. Check out [barriers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier.html) or you could just use a space widget to float atop the button to constrain other views. There is no a lot of ability to dynamically set guidelines.